# Errors lifting Sails.js Docker image in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: docker, sails.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running my Sails.js app in AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EB) in a Docker image. My workflow is to build the Docker image locally, push to ECR and then deploy my AWS config (eg: `Dockerrun.aws.json` and other config for Nginx). My app is a POC to test different tech integrations, so yes I'm using the MemoryStore for now, however I've mostly followed the [Deployment Guide](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/deployment)

Running my Docker image locally (in production mode by setting the `NODE_ENV` to `production`) the container/app starts fine and is ready to serve. I built a Nginx image that mimics EB's reverse proxy so I could test SSL termination, secure cookies, etc locally (using docker-compose to tie everything together) and it all works really nicely.

However when I deploy to EB my container/app takes a long time to boot. Pulling the logs I see:

```
debug: Please note: since `sails.config.session.cookie.secure` is set to `true`, the session cookie 
debug: will _only_ be sent over TLS connections (i.e. secure https:// requests).
debug: Requests made via http:// will not include a session cookie!
debug: 
debug: For more help:
debug:  • https://sailsjs.com/config/session#?the-secure-flag
debug:  • https://sailsjs.com/config/session#?do-i-need-an-ssl-certificate
debug:  • https://sailsjs.com/config/sails-config-http#?properties
debug:  • https://sailsjs.com/support
debug: 
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
[33mwarn[39m: The default `sails-disk` adapter is not designed for use as a production database.
[33mwarn[39m: Instead, please use another adapter like sails-postgresql or sails-mongo.
[33mwarn[39m: For more info, see: http://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/deployment
[33mwarn[39m: To hide this warning message, enable `sails.config.orm.skipProductionWarnings`.
[33mwarn[39m:  [?] If you're unsure, see https://sailsjs.com/support
[31merror[39m: Failed to lift app:

... repeats the above ~30 times

debug: Please note: since `sails.config.session.cookie.secure` is set to `true`, the session cookie 
debug: will _only_ be sent over TLS connections (i.e. secure https:// requests).
debug: Requests made via http:// will not include a session cookie!
debug: 
debug: For more help:
debug:  • https://sailsjs.com/config/session#?the-secure-flag
debug:  • https://sailsjs.com/config/session#?do-i-need-an-ssl-certificate
debug:  • https://sailsjs.com/config/sails-config-http#?properties
debug:  • https://sailsjs.com/support
debug: 
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
[33mwarn[39m: The default `sails-disk` adapter is not designed for use as a production database.
[33mwarn[39m: Instead, please use another adapter like sails-postgresql or sails-mongo.
[33mwarn[39m: For more info, see: http://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/deployment
[33mwarn[39m: To hide this warning message, enable `sails.config.orm.skipProductionWarnings`.
[33mwarn[39m:  [?] If you're unsure, see https://sailsjs.com/support
[32minfo[39m: 
[32minfo[39m:                .-..-.
[32minfo[39m: 
[32minfo[39m:    Sails              <|    .-..-.
[32minfo[39m:    v1.2.2              |\
[32minfo[39m:                       /|.\
[32minfo[39m:                      / || \
[32minfo[39m:                    ,'  |'  \
[32minfo[39m:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
[32minfo[39m:                 `--'-------' 
[32minfo[39m:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
[32minfo[39m:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
[32minfo[39m: 
[32minfo[39m: Server lifted in `/usr/src/app`
[32minfo[39m: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.
[32minfo[39m: Read more at https://sailsjs.com/support.
[34mdebug[39m: -------------------------------------------------------
[34mdebug[39m: :: Thu Sep 05 2019 06:22:35 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
[34mdebug[39m: Environment : production
[34mdebug[39m: Port        : 1337
[34mdebug[39m: -------------------------------------------------------
```

I do not know why I'm getting `[31merror[39m: Failed to lift app:` in my logs in EB but not locally, given I'm using Docker. Are there any logs in the container I should be pulling (I'm new to Sails but I thought it prints everything to the console)?

I'm wondering if it's to do with the building of the assets for production mode that's causing an error somehow. Is there way to precompile the assets? I can then run the command when building the image which will save time when deploying the image/container into the EB box.

**UPDATE**:

Since upgrading to `sails@1.2.3` I've gotten more informative errors

```
2019-09-14T11:17:29.226Z warn:  [?] If you're unsure, see https://sailsjs.com/support
2019-09-14T11:19:29.084Z error: Failed to lift app:Sails is taking too long to load.

--  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
 Troubleshooting tips:
  -• Were you still reading/responding to an interactive prompt?
     (Whoops, sorry!  Please lift again and try to respond a bit more quickly.)

  -• Do you have a lot of stuff in `assets/`?  Grunt might still be running.
    (Try increasing the hook timeout.  Currently it is 300000.
     e.g. `sails lift --hookTimeout=600000`)

  -• Is `grunt` a custom or 3rd party hook?
    (*If* `initialize()` is using a callback, make sure it's being called.)
--  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
```

I increased the hook timeout in `config/env/production.js` by adding `hookTimeout: 300000`

I assume the timeout is in milliseconds, thus I set the timeout to be 5 minutes. However Sails is only waiting 2 minutes according to the new logs. Have I increased the timeout correctly?

**UPDATE:**

I suspect that the building of assets contributes. I decreased the launch time from 6+ minutes to 3 minutes by precompiling the assets as part of building the Docker image.

1. Copy `tasks/register/prod.js` to `tasks/register/docker-prod.js` (or whatever you want) and rename the task to match the filename (eg: `docker-prod`)
2. Create/edit `tasks/register/prod.js` to contain

```
// don't build assets as part of running prod; 'docker-prod' instead
grunt.registerTask('prod', []);
```

3. Add the following to your `Dockerfile`

```
# Build the assets for Docker
RUN ./node_modules/.bin/grunt docker-prod
```

Comment: Why memory store you are using in production.js

Comment: @VikasKumar For this particular environment, as the logs say the `sails-disk`/`MemoryStore` I am wondering if it's because the container's filesystem is an EBS volume and thus network lag or other AWS environment setup is causing the startup delay.